# Reading list of json files using for loop

Tags: r

I am trying to read list of json files in my local folder. But the below code does not work. Can anyone help me in solving this

```
json_files <- list.files(pattern = "*.json")
for(i in length(json_files))
{
json_data3[[i]] <- fromJSON(paste(readLines[[i]],collapse = ""))
}
```

Comment: I think instead of `readLines[[i]]` you want `readLines(json_files[[i]])`.

Comment: What do you need the readLines for? `fromJSON(json_files[i])` is how I usually read them in.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure, which json library you are using, but it looks like jsonlite:

```
library(jsonlite)

json_data <- lapply(list.files(pattern = "*.json"), read_json)
json_data2 <- lapply(list.files(pattern = "*.json"), fromJSON)
```

To preserve the names of your files as list entries you can do:

```
names(json_data) <- list.files(pattern= "*.json")
# OR
json_data3 <- sapply(list.files(pattern="*.json"),FUN = read_json,
                     simplify = FALSE,USE.NAMES = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi. thanks. It worked for me. Is it possible to have the file name in list ? right now i do not get from which file I have extracted the data

Comment: The lazy mans solution is names(json_data) <- list.files(pattern="*.json"), but i also edited the main post